# Live zoomed view in an inset kind of box , when clicking pictures on camera view in iOS

Tags: ios, camera, zooming, live

I wan't to achieve the following thing:

-->  When  user tries to click picture through app ,i want to add another small rectangular view in which zoomed view is visible live while capturing image(which is seen by camera). Is it possible? I mean i have found that live streaming of camera is possible but that is in case of video.[image]

I want to see zoomed view live when user moves camera.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that is possible in new device only (iphone5 and 5s) with ios 7.1

Comment: @MitsBhadeshiya can yu give some link to follow or how to do that?

Comment: i am giving you link of my answer you have to customise as per your requirement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753499/custom-camera-zoom-in-out-while-recording-video-using-avfoundation/23106879#23106879

Comment: @MitsBhadeshiya i am using camera in photo capturing mode, not video.You think it will work for that too?

Comment: i am not sure but work also for photo.

Comment: didn't worked..@MitsBhadeshiya