# is zooming possible while recording video in avfoundation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video, avfoundation

I have been working with avfoundation and trying to zoom the video and record or zooming while recording by following code

```
    [CaptureSession startRunning];
     NSError *error;
    [VideoDevice lockForConfiguration:&error];
    [VideoDevice setActiveFormat:[VideoDevice.formats objectAtIndex:15]];
    [VideoDevice rampToVideoZoomFactor:5.0 withRate:1.0];
    [VideoDevice unlockForConfiguration];
```

and when I call

```
 [MovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];
```

it is throwing

```
[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:] - no active/enabled connections.'
```

If I just take a still image then the zoom is working and I can capture still image but I can not only capture video after zooming or zooming while recording.

From this should I infer that still video zooming is not supported by IOS ?

Also I think when I change the video active format which support zoom, it causes the crash, though I am using

```
[CaptureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];
```

in my configuration.

Please advice!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Camera zoom in/out while recording video using AVFoundation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753499/custom-camera-zoom-in-out-while-recording-video-using-avfoundation)

Comment: @Roecrew would you please carefully read my question ? I have done same things which you mentioned but my question is that how to zoom rather how to zoom while recording.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using "lockForConfiguration:" to get the lock but you are not checking if the lock was received successfully.
So, you should user "if" block for confirmation.

```
if( [_camera lockForConfiguration:nil] )
{
//push your stuff here.

[_camera unlockForConfiguration]
}
```

Comment: Did the same thing but no luck! Did you try it before ?

Comment: No luck! Did you really tried the zoom thing ? I wonder. I wrote this if block but it is not working. Could you please post snippet if you have working code ?